# Tracking an object via OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to track an object and mask or Hide it (a CODE in this case) using OpenCV and Python. As example I am using this video , the code will showing on 1min19s : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eu01hxoxmd3ns5f/capture-3.mp4?dl=0

What I need is to keep track on the CODE  and mask or Hide it as the video  without detecting other parts of the video as the code. Tracking by colour doesn't work here.

Any idea for a good approach on this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the object you are trying to track? What is a "CODE"? There's nothing in the video that makes it clear what you're after. And the source and result appear to be the same.

Comment: Aha, so there's some text in the form of an alphanumeric code that gets overlaid on the image in the lower left corner of the screen. That's the sort of detail we need in the question. And you want to detect it and then remove it?

Comment: Yes, but i dont known when and where it will show up in the video bcus its Live stream .. i want if the Code appears Hide it , as the video ..

Answer (score 0):

Tracking is much more complex than searching the similar colour. OpenCV has implemented some tracking algorithms, what you need to do is to use the existing apis to solve the problem. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html) is an introduction to OpenCV tracker.

If you do not stick to OpenCV, [dlib](http://dlib.net/) is also a c++ library with python interface which also implements object tracking algorithms.

Comment: yes , i want track and mask the code when showing .. bcus i want use that on stream live

Comment: So it is not known when and where it will show up in the video? Then I guess what you want is a detector and video watermark remover instead of a tracker.